# Merging similar HashMaps in java

Tags: java, hashmap

`HashMap<String, String> hashMap1`:

```
       name : ranjith
       city : san jose
```

`HashMap<String, String> hashMap2`:

```
       name : sandeep
       city : san jose
```

`HashMap<String, String> hashMap3`:

```
       name : rohith
       city : san jose
```

I want to convert the above hashmaps into `HashMap<String, List<String>> hashMap4`:

```
      name : [ranjith, sandeep, rohith]
      city : [san jose]
```

To do this merging is there any direct way, or should I go through Iterating each element, finding similarities and then merging

Comment: What's with the parentheses?

Comment: all the values are merged and put into a list , I kept parenthesis so that it  indicates a list

Comment: Are the keys (name, city) fixed, or can they vary at runtime?

Comment: No, there can be different set of keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will collect to a `Map<String, Set<String>>`, which seems more appropriate than a list, since you're collecting unique values. It uses a static import of `java.util.stream.Collectors.*`.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> hashMap4 = Stream.of(hashMap1, hashMap2, hashMap3)
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toSet())));
```

---

Here's the Java 7 version. Not as clean and concise, but still not too complicated.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> hashMap4 = new HashMap<>();
for (Map<String, String> map : Arrays.asList(hashMap1, hashMap2, hashMap3)) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Set<String> values = hashMap4.get(key);
        if (values == null) {
            hashMap4.put(key, values = new HashSet<>());
        }
        values.add(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have some errors using this package "java.util.stream.Collectors.*" in android. Can you help me out

Comment: @ranjithGampa If you're using android, you're probably on Java 7, so you'll have to do this by hand most likely.